# Converting FeatureLayer to graphics using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#

How do I convert a Map or FeatureLayer to graphics on ArcObjects 10.1?

**Problem Solved**

this is the working code:

```
    private void Convert_to_graphics( IMapDocument doc)
    {

        IMap pmap;
        IFeature pFeature;
        IElement pElement = null;
        IMarkerElement pp = new MarkerElementClass();
        IGraphicsContainer pGraphicsContainer;
        IActiveView pActiveView;

        pmap = doc.get_Map(0);
        pActiveView = doc.ActiveView; 
        //pGraphicsContainer = doc.ActiveView.GraphicsContainer;


        int[] array = {8 , 7 , 6 , 5 , 1}; //layers indexes , 

        pGraphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)pmap; 
        foreach (var i in array)
        {


            IGeoFeatureLayer fl = (IGeoFeatureLayer)pmap.get_Layer(i);
            IFeatureClass fc = fl.FeatureClass;

            IFeatureCursor fcur =   fc.Search(null, false);

            IFeatureRenderer fr = fl.Renderer;

            pFeature = fcur.NextFeature()  ; 

            while (pFeature  != null)
            {

                if (pFeature.Shape.GeometryType == ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint)
                {
                    IMarkerElement pmkElement = new MarkerElementClass();

                        ISymbol sym = fr.get_SymbolByFeature(pFeature);

                        pmkElement.Symbol = (IMarkerSymbol)sym;

                        pElement = (IElement)pmkElement;


                }
                if (pFeature.Shape.GeometryType == ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
                {
                    ILineElement pmkElement = new LineElementClass();
                    pmkElement.Symbol = (ILineSymbol)fr.get_SymbolByFeature(pFeature);
                    pElement = (IElement)pmkElement;
                }
                if (pFeature.Shape.GeometryType == ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
                {
                    IFillShapeElement pmkElement = new PolygonElementClass();
                    pmkElement.Symbol = (IFillSymbol)fr.get_SymbolByFeature(pFeature);
                    pElement = (IElement)pmkElement;
                }


                if (pElement != null)
                {
                    pElement.Geometry = pFeature.Shape;

                    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pElement, 0);
                }

                pFeature = fcur.NextFeature();
            }




      }

            pActiveView.Refresh();


    }
```

Comment: This is a very old question but I think it would still benefit from having the "answer in question" extracted out to be a true answer.  Note that the question body left as a result would be too brief by today's GIS SE standards so maybe that could be expanded a little too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Convert Features to Graphic Elements](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/Samples/ArcMap/ConvertFeaturesToGraphics.htm) VBA code sample.  I would modify it so that the element's symbol gets set to whatever is returned by [IFeatureRenderer.SymbolByFeature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004wv000000).  The interface used to set the symbol will depend on the underlying coclass (for PolygonElement use IFillShapeElement).